# std::filesystem::copy() only copies files in folder

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems

I am trying to copy a folder to another folder using `std::filesystem::copy()`, so far it only copies the files and folders within the folder I'm trying to move over, instead of the folder itself. Any ideas why?

I know this could be done manually by creating a new directory using `std::filesystem::create_directory()`, but it won't carry over the security info and permissions from the original folder.

EDIT:

path = C:\Users\Test\Folder
nPath = C:\Users\Test\Movehere

```
boolean CopyToPath(std::string path, std::string nPath) {
    if (fs::exists(path) && fs::exists(nPath)) {
        try {
            //path = Folder To Copy, nPath = Destination
            fs::copy(path, nPath, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing | fs::copy_options::recursive);

            return true;
        }
        catch (fs::filesystem_error e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n";

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What are the two paths?

Comment: path = C:\Users\Test\Folder nPath = C:\Users\Test\Movehere

Comment: Try to copy to the path `C:/Users/Test/Movehere/` or `C:/Users/Test/Movehere/.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior, as documented at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy:

> - Otherwise, if `from` is a directory and either `options` has `copy_options::recursive` or is `copy_options::none`,
>
>   - If `to` does not exist, first executes `create_directory(to, from)` (creates the new directory with a copy of the old directory's attributes)
>   - Then, whether `to` already existed or was just created, **iterates over the files contained in `from`** as if by `for (const std::filesystem::directory_entry& x : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(from))` and for each directory entry, recursively calls `copy(x.path(), to/x.path().filename(), options | in-recursive-copy)`, where *in-recursive-copy* is a special bit that has no other effect when set in `options`. (The sole purpose of setting this bit is to prevent recursive copying subdirectories if `options` is `copy_options::none`.)

In other words, `copy()` does not copy the source directory itself, only the *contents* of the directory.

If your goal is to make a copy of `Folder` itself inside of `Movehere`, ie `C:\Users\Test\Movehere\Folder`, then you will have to extract `Folder` from the source directory and append it to the target path, eg:

```cpp
fs::path src = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Folder";
fs::path dest = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Movehere";

dest /= src.filename();
fs::create_directory(dest, src);
// only because CopyToPath() requires this due
// to its use of fs::exists(), instead of letting
// fs::copy() create it...

CopyToPath(src, dest);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll just use this and find another way to copy security and permissions

Comment: @XprtSekz `create_directory()` can handle that for you, when you create a new folder specifying an existing folder to copy attributes from

Comment: @XprtSekz: If your source is a directory, and the destination directory does not exist, `copy` will already copy the permissions from the source to the destination, as if by `create_directory(destination, source)`.